# What darknet would you choose (or is it not justifiable)?

Tags: energy, electricity, green-it, computing, internet

I want to know if there are any darknets that are sustainable. I have my doubts about Tor due to their apparent interest in Proof of Work.

https://blog.torproject.org/stop-the-onion-denial

> In particular, onion services can ask the client to solve a Proof-of-Work puzzle before allowing entry. With the right Proof-of-Work algorithm and puzzle difficulty, this can make it impossible for an attacker to overwhelm the service, while still making it reachable by normal clients with only a small delay. Similar designs have also been proposed for TLS.

I2P developers (on zzz.i2p, the site would not work unless you use I2P) have shown interest in using the same method against DDoS attacks as well. In addition to the whole kovri thing, targeting usage of a PoW cryptocurrency(Monero).

Gnunet also appears to be using PoW.

https://gnunet.org/en/faq.html

> The gnunet-service-nse process will initially compute a so-called "proof-of-work" which is used to convince the network that your peer is real (or, rather, make it        expensive for an adversary to mount a Sybil attack on the network size estimator). The calculation is expected to take a few days, depending on how fast your CPU is. If the CPU load is creating a problem for you, you can set the value "WORKDELAY" in the "nse" section of your configuration file to a higher value. The default is "5 ms".

The Safe Network use Proof of Resource instead of PoW.

https://safenetwork.tech/faq/

> Proof of Resource is the process that measures a Node’s ability to store and retrieve data chunks. A User’s computer receives a score based on its CPU speed, bandwidth availability, disk space and time online.

> Proof of Resource in the Safe Network uses a mechanism similar to a Zero Knowledge Proof. The checking mechanism does not need to know what data is being checked—it simply needs to know that the correct data is being held and accurately.

While I think that is better in theory, they still encourage bitcoin transactions on the same page.
Their forums also show that it encourages usage beyond just  spare resources:
https://safenetforum.org/t/best-farming-hardware/99

The Nym network uses Proof of Mixing, which is based on Proof of work.

https://nymtech.net/nym-whitepaper.pdf

> The NYM rewards nodes that provision a high quality of service via a novel proof-of-work scheme,proof of mixing, which proves that a mix node has been adequately routing traffic.

So far I have seen two somewhat promising networks, Freenet and Lokinet.

Freenet, like I2P and Safe Network, encourages 24 hour usage, though this is not strictly necessary. What makes it interesting is that you can limit who you connect to, making it possible to only make direct connections to people using renewable electricity.
You could also encourage those people to do the same themselves. You also do not need to stay online after uploading content(including sites) as it is distributed.

Lokinet used to use PoW, but now uses PoS(Proof of Stake).

https://loki.network/2019/10/02/does-pulse-make-the-rich-richer/

> Recently we released our fifth Loki Improvement Proposal in which we outlined a new Proof of Stake scheme, Pulse. If it’s to be implemented, Pulse would have Service Nodes produce blocks, order transactions, and secure the blockchain, rendering miners in the Loki ecosystem no longer necessary.

https://oxen.io/blog/clean-crypto

> At Oxen, we’ve already rolled out our Proof of Stake implementation, Pulse. Thanks to the full removal of Proof of Work, Oxen is more efficient and eco-friendly than ever. With the technical requirements and specifications for a service node, and assuming it is running 24/7, a service node can be expected to chew up about 1,400 KWh per year. With 1,700 service nodes, the network would consume 2,380,000 KWh in a year.
> Rounding up (just in case), Oxen still only uses 0.0025TWh a year.
> Oxen uses 0.002% of the energy Bitcoin uses.
> And only 0.006% of the energy consumption of Ethereum.

If care a lot about both sustainability and privacy/anonymity, what would you choose, and why? Would you pick a different route?
(Assume I myself use energy from renewable resources if that makes a difference)

EDIT1:
I just found found some new information related to Tor:
https://blog.torproject.org/nft-auction-and-whats-next

> We wanted to be mindful of the impact of the blockchain on climate change. Part of our decision to move forward came after we looked into the efforts Ethereum has been putting forward to address their part in this—here is a blog post from them that just came out about moving ETH from PoW to PoS and what this means for ETH’s climate impact.
> We also decided that instead of buying carbon offsets as part of this auction, we would put money in the hands of those who are on the frontlines fighting for our planet. We chose to donate to the Munduruku Wakoborũn Women's Association, a grassroots indigenous organization in Pará, Brazil.

Comment: While a tor site COULD implement PoW, I have not come across one that does, they all use captcha's.  Would "tor without PoW" meet your requirements?

Comment: I am unsure how I would be able to tell if a site uses PoW though.

Comment: Would a site be able to run PoW without javascript ?